# Why are carbocations electrophiles

Tags: organic-chemistry

My lecturer taught that carbocations are electron-short, and are therefore positively charged. He then went on to say they are electrophiles, that is they accept electrons.

However, he taught last semester that electrons are donated for a substance to become a cation.
And this is very confusing.

Comment: It seems that you misunderstood your lecturer. If a compounds looses electrons it becomes a cation.

Comment: If you get conflicting information, it is mostly easy to verify it on independent offline on online sources, what should be preferred to asking. The latter leads to flooding internet with redundant questions and answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your professor is right in his explanations. Consider the following example, you start with (CH${_3}$)$_3$CCl (tert-butylchloride) and then try doing a transformation where you want the Cl$^-$ to be replaced by some other group. It is known that if we try to remove Cl from a molecule, it would leave as Cl$^-$, meaning that the tert-butyl group that is now left behind is short of two electrons (one from the tert-butyl part, and one from chloride), in comparison to tert-butylchloride, which means that it will now have a positive charge, becoming tert-butyl cation.

Answer (score -1):

Any cation is missing electrons.  Think of regular metal ions.  A sodium atom has 11 protons and 11 electrons.  The sodium ion ($\ce{Na+}$) has 11 protons and 10 electrons.  The ion has fewer electrons than protons, resulting in a positive charge.

The same is true for carbon.  Carbocations are electron-deficient, which is why they have a positive charge.

Some cations are stable (like $\ce{Na+}) and are not electrophilic.  However, carbocations are generally not stable, and are going to react with electron-rich species.  They are electrophiles.

Your confusion might be in the wording.  In order for a carbon atom to become a carbocation, it must donate electrons.  Once it is electron-deficient, it is now an electrophile.